# Trying to loop a playlist in folder with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, loops, ffmpeg

When trying to play all of *.mp4 files in the folder, and then repeat it from the first video again, i get this error:

```
start_betterme_playlist: line 35: 25659 Killed                  ffmpeg $SOURCE -filter_complex "$filter" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 512k -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

The code is - Does anybody maybe know how to fix that problem, i really would like to have this multiple videos played on the stream contiounsly. Thanks in advance!

```
#! /bin/bash


VBR="2500k"                                    
FPS="30"                                      
QUAL="medium"                                 
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/"  

FOLDER="videos"                                  
KEY="live_16xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxvO7C"                 

SOURCE=""
n=0
filter=""

for f in $FOLDER/*.mp4
do
  SOURCE="$SOURCE -i $f"
  filter="$filter [$n:v:0] [$n:a:0]"
  ((n++))
done

filter="$filter concat=n=$n:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]"

echo "ffmpeg $SOURCE -filter_complex '$filter'"

ffmpeg \
    $SOURCE -filter_complex "$filter" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -deinterlace \
    -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 512k \
    -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg's built in playlist feature:

1. Create a **playlist** of all mp4 files in your directory (you can use a filler-video between the videos)
2. Use **playlist** as input for ffmpeg (edit ffmpeg commands to taste. I created a multicast stream that can be easily tested locally)

here is a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create playlist from all .mp4 and play in loop

playlist="playlist.txt"

# create/reset playlist file
echo "#ffmpeg playlist" > ${playlist}

# this video goes in between two video files
use_filler="true" # activate filler with "true". Use "false" or any other string to deactivate filler.
filler="filler.mp4"

# create playlist for ffmpeg from all videos in the current directory
for f in *.mp4;do

# exclude filler from playlist
if [ "${f}" != "${filler}" ]; then

    echo "file '${f}'" >> ${playlist}

    # if activated add filler after every video file
    if [[ "${use_filler}" = "true" ]]; then  # This condition is false for anything but the literal string "true".

        echo "file '${filler}'" >> ${playlist}

    fi

fi

done

# stream playlist immediately with ffmpeg
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -stream_loop -1 \
-i "${playlist}" \
-c copy \
-f mpegts \
"udp://239.253.253.1:1234?pkt_size=1384"
```

Playback with ffplay...

```
ffplay udp://239.253.253.1:1234
```

...or VLC:

```
udp://@239.253.253.1:1234
```

Comment: it doesn't loop the playlist though (plays once and then stops)

Comment: I've tested the script. It does loop infinitely.